# How to send e-mail from Silverlight without ASP.NET server?

Tags: silverlight, apache, email

My task is simple, send an e-mail from a Silverlight app, but it has to work in most webservers so, Linux, Apache. Cannot use Windows Servers.

Is my best bet to create a simple PHP script to do the heavy lifting and make request to that using SL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with a ASP.NET you would need to write code server side to accept a request from SL to send an email.  Ok so Visual Studio would make creating that much easier but essentially either with PHP, ASP, ASP.NET or whatever you need a service to for SL to send its request to send an email.

I know very little about Apache but PHP would be one way to do it, although I'm sure there would be other ways to create a web service that SL could consume.

Comment: Expanding on this a bit, the "right" answer is to define the required "service" (http request, of the appropriate type - I don't have my REST cheat sheet to hand but not GET!). So your Silverlight app will expect to call a service with the defined signature you can then provide sample implementations of same in ASP.NET and php which should cover the majority of cases.